# Как упростить код при присваивании значений по определенным правилам (напр. по таблице истинности)

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода, логические-выражения

Предметная область - АРМ с визуализацией технологического процесса.

Представим, что есть несколько одинаковых устройств, у которых есть два состояния: открыт/закрыт. Представлено это булевыми переменными:

```
bool firstDeviceOpened  = x;
bool secondDeviceOpened = y;
```

Есть перечисление, описанное примерно так:

```
enum State {
    STATE_NOTHING_OPENED, 
    STATE_FIRST_OPENED,
    STATE_SECOND_OPENED,
    STATE_ALL_OPENED
};
```

Состояния могут быть следующие (0 и 1 - "закрыт" и "открыт" соответственно):

```
device1 | device2 |        method
-----------------------------------------
   0    |    0    | STATE_NOTHING_OPENED
   1    |    0    | STATE_FIRST_OPENED
   0    |    1    | STATE_SECOND_OPENED
   1    |    1    | STATE_ALL_OPENED
```

Имея все это, необходимо инициализировать переменную состояния текущим состоянием. В проекте эти инициализация реализована примерно так:

```
State currentState = STATE_NOTHING_OPENED;

if (firstDeviceOpened && !secondDeviceOpened)
{
    currentState = STATE_FIRST_OPENED;
}

if (!firstDeviceOpened && secondDeviceOpened)
{
    currentState = STATE_SECOND_OPENED;
}

if (firstDeviceOpened && secondDeviceOpened)
{
    currentState = STATE_ALL_OPENED;
}

... 
// где-то дальше сидит switch, который по состоянию запускает 
// методы, отображающие смену состояния на визуализации
```

Собственно проблема в том, что при добавлении еще одного девайса нужно городить еще кучу условий. В итоге, как-то грустно поддерживать 2<sup>N</sup> условий, где N - кол-во девайсов.

Еще одни палки в колеса ставит ситуация, когда появляются девайсы, которые работают в "*особых случаях*", например:

```
// если оба закрыты, открывается третье устройство
bool thirdDeviceOpened = !(firstDeviceOpened || secondDeviceOpened);
```

Как избавиться от необходимости городить кучу `if`-ов и обрабатывать состояния для каждой отдельной комбинации?

Comment: ну таблицу тоже будет не просто поддерживать

Comment: Ну если таблица истинности является входными данными, то зачем вам все эти `if`? берете и смотрите значение из таблицы за одно действие

Comment: @VTT, не совсем понял, что Вы имеете ввиду... Можно небольшой пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй битовые флаги:

```
enum State : uint32_t {
    STATE_NOTHING_OPENED = 0x00
    STATE_FIRST_OPENED   = 0x01,
    STATE_SECOND_OPENED  = 0x02,
    STATE_THIRD_OPENED   = 0x04,
    STATE_ALL_OPENED     = STATE_NOTHING_OPENED|STATE_FIRST_OPENED|STATE_THIRD_OPENED
}

// ..

uint32_t state=0;

if (firstDeviceOpened ) {state |= STATE_FIRST_OPENED ; }
if (secondDeviceOpened) {state |= STATE_SECOND_OPENED; }
if (thirdDeviceOpened ) {state |= THIRD_SECOND_OPENED; }

// ..

if (state & STATE_ALL_OPENED) {
  showMessage ("Взрыв реактора неизбежен! Покайтесь в грехах!");
  runAlarm ();
  pray ();
}
```